# Complex LINQ query to build two lists, cast each value in each list, and combine lists?

Tags: c#, linq

I have three interfaces in my application

```
public interface FBBase { }
public interface IFoo : FBBase { }
public interface IBar : FBBase { }
```

I also have a class that holds a `List` of both `IFoo` and `IBar`

```
public class FBUser
{
    public List<IFoo> foos { get; set; }
    public List<IBar> bars { get; set; }
}
```

And some classes that implement these interfaces

```
public class Fee : IFoo { }
public class Baz : IBar { }
public class PhiBat : IFoo, IBar { }
```

In another class I do some work with `FBUser` objects. I would like to collect a `List<IFBBase>` that contains each unique reference in `FBUser.foos` and `FBUser.bars`. Furthermore I would like to also disclude certain `Type` from the `List<IFBBase>`.

**Is there a cleaner way to do it than this? Is this the correct way to do it?**

```
public class FBUserWorker
{
    List<Type> discludeTypes { get; set; } = new List<Type>();

    public FBUserWorker()
    {
        discludeTypes.Add(typeof(PhiBat));
    }

    public void DoWork(FBUser userObj)
    {
        var fbBaseList = userObj.foos.Where(x => !discludeTypes.Contains(x.GetType())).Cast<IFBBase>().ToList();
        fbBaseList.AddRange(userObj.bars.Where(x => !discludeTypes.Contains(x.GetType())).Cast<IFBBase>().ToList());
        fbBaseList = fbBaseList.Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Concat` to merge the lists (converted to `IEnumerable<IFBase>`) and then run the `Where` and `Distinct` logic:

```
result = userObj.foos.Cast<IFBBase>()
            .Concat(userObj.bars.Cast<IFBase>())
            .Where(x => !discludeTypes.Contains(x.GetType()))
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```